# Move object based on its angle

Tags: javascript, math, typescript

I am trying moving an object based on its rotation, and I have 4 methods:

- forward
- backward
- up
- down

Of the 4 methods, only `forward` and `backward` seem to be working properly. The other two seem to have a different effect based on the rotation. When it is set to a 90 degree rotation it acts the same as `forward` (forward is down the screen at this rotation), but in reality the desired affect is for it to move right.

[image: Rotation Image]

These two methods seem to be working properly:

```
public get forward(): Vector2 {
    return new Vector2(
        Math.cos(this.rotation.degrees * (Math.PI / 180)),
        Math.sin(this.rotation.degrees * (Math.PI / 180))
    );
}

public get backward(): Vector2 {
    return new Vector2(
        -Math.cos(this.rotation.degrees * (Math.PI / 180)),
        -Math.sin(this.rotation.degrees * (Math.PI / 180))
    );
}
```

These two however are not working properly. I can not seem to figure out what is causing this, I assumed the math would be similar, maybe I am wrong on that?

```
public get up(): Vector2 {
    return new Vector2(
        Math.cos(this.rotation.degrees * (Math.PI / 180)),
        -Math.sin(this.rotation.degrees * (Math.PI / 180))
    );
}

public get down(): Vector2 {
    return new Vector2(
        -Math.cos(this.rotation.degrees * (Math.PI / 180)),
        Math.sin(this.rotation.degrees * (Math.PI / 180))
    );
}
```

Comment: this.rotation.degrees is giving you correct degrees?

Comment: Yeah, it is a set value, it is created like so (last param): `instantiate(Guy, Stage.topLeftQuad, new Rotation(90));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate it this way: `up` is +90 degrees from `forward`, `down` is -90 degrees from `forward` (and `backward` is just 180 degrees from `forward`).

In other words:

```
public get up(): Vector2 {
    const phi = (this.rotation.degrees + 90) * (Math.PI / 180);
    return new Vector2(
        Math.cos(phi),
        Math.sin(phi)
    );
}
```

Negating `cos` / `sin` without the other clearly isn't correct. Just `-cos`, for example, just means "move in the opposite direction in the x axis and keep the y axis velocity the same". The case where `forward` points North-Northeast, for example, would create a vector going North-Northwest.

Comment: This seems to work. I am using a canvas, so it seems like doing `-90` it moves the right direction is that the right way?

Comment: Yes, you may need to flip `+90` / `-90` depending on how you define `up` and `down` within your own coordinate system

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate cos and sin for main direction once, then vector components are:

```
forward:            cos,   sin
backward:          -cos,   -sin
up(really left):   -sin,    cos
down(really right): sin,   -cos
```